# how to add cdata to an xml file using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, cdata

I am trying to wrap CDATA for the elements in an xml file.

Another point i missed was, there are some elements with same names those need to be escaped from adding CDATA.

This is the source xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<books>
    <jndi:binding name="books/cat/action/configs">
        <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
            <urlConfig>
              <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
              <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>
              <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>
            </urlConfig>
        </jndi:value>
    </jndi:binding>
    <jndi:binding name="books/cat/romance/configs">
        <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
            <urlConfig>
              <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>          
              <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>          
              <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>  
            </urlConfig>
        </jndi:value>
    </jndi:binding>
<jndi:binding name="books/cat/thriller/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
        abc.com
    </jndi:value>
</jndi:binding> 
<jndi:binding name="books/cat/classic/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
        abc.com
    </jndi:value>
</jndi:binding>
</books>
```

I have tried to use the same trick that @Dimitre Novatchev has mentioned here at [How to insert CDATA into XML text markup exported from Access 2003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741611/how-to-insert-cdata-into-xml-text-markup-exported-from-access-2003). But some how that's not working for me.

This is the xsl file that i tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"  >
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can some one suggest me how to add CDATA to an element and also need to add an additional line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` at the beginning of CDATA.

Here is the expected out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<books>
    <jndi:binding name="books/cat/action/configs">
        <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
        <![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
            <urlConfig>
              <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
              <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>
              <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>
            </urlConfig>
        ]]> 
        </jndi:value>
    </jndi:binding>
    <jndi:binding name="books/cat/romance/configs">
        <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
        <![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
            <urlConfig>
              <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>          
              <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>          
              <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
                <address>abc.com</address>
              </urlKey>  
            </urlConfig>
        ]]> 
        </jndi:value>
    </jndi:binding>
<jndi:binding name="books/cat/thriller/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
        abc.com
    </jndi:value>
</jndi:binding> 
<jndi:binding name="books/cat/classic/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
        abc.com
    </jndi:value>
</jndi:binding>
</books>
```

Comment: namespaceURI is: xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to convert the XML that goes inside the `CDATA` sections into text. This XSLT should do the job:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="jndi:value"/>

  <xsl:template match="jndi:value">
    <xsl:copy>
      <!-- Copy the attributes -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
      <!-- Convert the contained nodes (elements and text) into text -->
      <xsl:variable name="subElementsText">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="asText"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <!-- Output the XML directive and the converted nodes -->
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-8&quot;?&gt;',$subElementsText)"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Copy text nodes as text -->
  <xsl:template match="text()" mode="asText">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Copy elements as text -->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="asText">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;',name())"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',name(),'=&quot;',.,'&quot;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <xsl:value-of select="'&gt;'"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()" mode="asText"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&lt;/',name(),'&gt;')"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically it uses a couple of templates to match the XML elements that need to be converted to text and convert them 'manually'. The `cdata-sections-elements` directive does the rest.

When applied to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<books xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
  <jndi:binding name="books/cat/action/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
      <urlConfig>
        <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
        <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
        <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
      </urlConfig>
    </jndi:value>
  </jndi:binding>
  <jndi:binding name="books/cat/romance/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">
      <urlConfig>
        <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"/>
        <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
        <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
      </urlConfig>
    </jndi:value>
  </jndi:binding>
</books>
```

produces the expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<books xmlns:jndi="urn:jboss:jndi-binding-service:1.0">
  <jndi:binding name="books/cat/action/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <urlConfig>
        <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"></defaults>
        <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
        <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
      </urlConfig>
    ]]></jndi:value>
  </jndi:binding>
  <jndi:binding name="books/cat/romance/configs">
    <jndi:value type="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <urlConfig>
        <defaults catID="1983" subcatID="1987" method="get" onError="keep"></defaults>
        <urlKey name="logo" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
        <urlKey name="logo1" altURL="def.com">
          <address>abc.com</address>
        </urlKey>
      </urlConfig>
    ]]></jndi:value>
  </jndi:binding>
</book
```

Comment: Hi @Mimo, Thanks for the code, I dont see the expected output , wondering how should i include `<![CDATA[
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> ` in the element.

Comment: I get the correct output - see above. The XSLT already adds the XML directive.

Comment: thanks for the detailed information, I forgot to mention this morning that i also need to skip some elements that are having same template match "jndi:value" from adding CDATA. Please check the updated source file and output.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge you cannot generate with a XSLT the same element sometimes with CDATA content and sometimes not. Having those elements with or without CDATA content should not make any difference though: in the end CDATA is just a way to simplify the coding, but the text a XML parser would load is exactly the same.

Comment: Is it possible to group the elements that need CDATA and that don't need CDATA. Example: If a name of the parent element is `<jndi:binding name="books/cat/romance/configs">` add a CDATA to that element else don't do any CDATA for that element.

Comment: how to add newline before CDATA section starts and ends, Example: `<jndi:value type="java.lang.String">new line<![CDATA[ ...... new line ]]>`

Comment: 'Is it possible to group the elements..': to the best of my knowledge no.

Comment: any idea how to add new line before CDATA and after end of CDATA.

Comment: No idea - but why would you want to do that..?

Comment: If i can put the CDATA in new line, I planning to put `<cdata>...</cdata>` for all the one's that i want to have CDATA sections, so once they are converted to CDATA, i can remove the unwanted nodes(in our case that would be `<cdata></cdata>` from an xml file. This way we can group CDATA elements and non CDATA elements.

Comment: ...why do you want only some CDATA? Having all CDATA (or none) does not make any difference in the actual content of the XML

Comment: because i have some jndi:bindings whose jndi:values are need to be in CDATA sections and some need to be in non cdata sections, So in order to accomplish this i am trying to add a new nodes <cdata></cdata> for the elements that need a CDATA so that i can match all <cdata></cdata> nodes and wrap CDATA section to them.

Comment: ...why some need to be in a CDATA section and other not? It should make no difference